# Vuejs & Auth0 : I need to reload page to be Authenticated

Tags: api, vue.js, authentication, vuejs3, auth0

I'm a beginner in Vue, and I implemented Auth0 to my Web App using Vue3.

My issue: after logging in, my API call to retrieve data get an unauthorized error 403. If I reload the page, everything is working fine.

What should I do to avoid reloading the page to get authenticated directly?

Here are my scripts:

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './index.css'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import Datepicker from 'vue3-date-time-picker'
import 'vue3-date-time-picker/dist/main.css'

import { setupAuth } from './auth/index.js'
import authConfig from './auth/config.js'

function callbackRedirect(appState) {
    router.push(appState && appState.targetUrl ? appState.targetUrl : '/' );
}

setupAuth(authConfig, callbackRedirect).then((auth) => {
    let app = createApp(App).use(router);
    app.config.globalProperties.$dayjs = dayjs;
    app.component('Datepicker', Datepicker);
    app.use(auth).mount('#app');
})
```

My App.vue script:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isAuthenticated">
    <NavBar />
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue'
export default {
  components: { NavBar },
  data(){
    return {
      isAuthenticated: false,
    }
  },

  async mounted(){
    await this.getAccessToken()
  },

  methods: {
    async getAccessToken(){
      try {
        const accessToken = await this.$auth.getTokenSilently()
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)
        this.isAuthenticated = true
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error occured while trying to retrieve Access Token...', error)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and my Home.vue loading the data:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="py-10">

      <header>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold leading-tight text-gray-900">Monitoring Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
      </header>


      <main>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <h3 class="m-5 text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Main KPIs</h3>
          <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
            <div v-for="(item, index) in stats" :key="index" class="md:col-span-1">
              <div class="bg-white p-5 border-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-lg mb-5">
                <span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 truncate">{{ item.name }}</span>
                <p class="mt-1 text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900">{{ parseFloat(item.stat.toFixed(2)) }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
import ProductsService from '../services/products.service'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data(){
    return{
      user: '',
      products: '',
      stats: '',
    }
  },

  async mounted(){
    await this.readProducts()
    await this.buildStats()
  },

  methods: {
    async readProducts(){
        let temp = null
        try {
          temp = await ProductsService.readProducts()
          this.products = temp.data
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error: cannot retrieve all products...')
        }
    },

    async buildStats(){
      //Nb products
      const nbProducts = this.products.length

      //Nb offers & Uniq NbRetailers
      let nbOffers = 0
      let retailers = []
      for(let product of this.products){
        for(let offer of product.offers){
          retailers.push(offer.retailer)
          nbOffers += 1
        }
      }
      const nbRetailers = _.uniq(retailers).length
      
      this.stats = [
        { name: 'Number of Retailers', stat: nbRetailers },
        { name: 'Number of Products', stat: nbProducts },
        { name: 'Number of Offers', stat: nbOffers },
      ]
    },
  },

  watch: {
    products: function(){
      this.buildStats()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My ./auth/index.js file:

```
import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js'
import { computed, reactive, watchEffect } from 'vue'

let client
const state = reactive({
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  popupOpen: false,
  error: null,
})

async function loginWithPopup() {
  state.popupOpen = true

  try {
    await client.loginWithPopup(0)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    state.popupOpen = false
  }

  state.user = await client.getUser()
  state.isAuthenticated = true
}

async function handleRedirectCallback() {
  state.loading = true

  try {
    await client.handleRedirectCallback()
    state.user = await client.getUser()
    state.isAuthenticated = true
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e
  } finally {
    state.loading = false
  }
}

function loginWithRedirect(o) {
  return client.loginWithRedirect(o)
}

function getIdTokenClaims(o) {
  return client.getIdTokenClaims(o)
}

function getTokenSilently(o) {
  return client.getTokenSilently(o)
}

function getTokenWithPopup(o) {
  return client.getTokenWithPopup(o)
}

function logout(o) {
  return client.logout(o)
}

export const authPlugin = {
  isAuthenticated: computed(() => state.isAuthenticated),
  loading: computed(() => state.loading),
  user: computed(() => state.user),
  getIdTokenClaims,
  getTokenSilently,
  getTokenWithPopup,
  handleRedirectCallback,
  loginWithRedirect,
  loginWithPopup,
  logout,
}

export const routeGuard = (to, from, next) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loading, loginWithRedirect } = authPlugin

  const verify = () => {
    // If the user is authenticated, continue with the route
    if (isAuthenticated.value) {
      return next()
    }

    // Otherwise, log in
    loginWithRedirect({ appState: { targetUrl: to.fullPath } })
  }

  // If loading has already finished, check our auth state using `fn()`
  if (!loading.value) {
    return verify()
  }

  // Watch for the loading property to change before we check isAuthenticated
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (loading.value === false) {
      return verify()
    }
  })
}

export const setupAuth = async (options, callbackRedirect) => {
  client = await createAuth0Client({
    ...options,
  })

  try {
    // If the user is returning to the app after authentication
    

    if (
      window.location.search.includes('code=') &&
      window.location.search.includes('state=')
    ) {
      // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
      const { appState } = await client.handleRedirectCallback()

      // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
      // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
      callbackRedirect(appState)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e
  } finally {
    // Initialize our internal authentication state
    state.isAuthenticated = await client.isAuthenticated()
    state.user = await client.getUser()
    state.loading = false
  }

  return {
    install: (app) => {
      app.config.globalProperties.$auth = authPlugin
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Most probably inside the code of `ProductsService.readProducts` you setup the bearer token to call the API and the token is null... Try to pu a `console.log` inside the `getAccessToken` AFTER the `this.isAuthenticated` and another after `temp = await ProductsService.readProducts()` to see if (maybe) the last one is called BEFORE the getaccessToken

Comment: Note that Vue doesn't await the lifecycle hooks, so `await`-ing an `async` call in `mounted` doesn't block the component from mounting. `Home.vue` is likely rendering before the auth token is set in `App.getAccessToken()`. You should probably move that into `main.js` before `createApp()`.

Comment: `this.$auth` is the same as `auth` in `main.js`. Just use it directly there: `auth.getTokenSilently()`.

Comment: When I'm adding const test = auth.getTokenSilently() in the setupAuth function inside main.js I got an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: auth.getTokenSilently is not a function

Comment: Actually it looks like `setupAuth` resolves to the plugin object `{ install() {} }`, but we want `authPlugin`. `import { authPlugin } from './auth'` at the top of the file, then `authPlugin.getTokenSilently()` within the `setupAuth()` call before `createApp()`.

Comment: Thanks @tony19. As suggested, I added authPlugin.getTokenSilently().then((accessToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)
    }) in the main.js app. If I retry, I still have the same error. I need to reload to get the data...